# HTTP: Unauthorized - Nextcloud on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nautilus, files, cloud, filemanager, nextcloud

I have configured my Nextcloud server in the respective Ubuntu 18.04 LTS settings (Settings-->Online Accounts-->Nextcloud) and I am using the correct login details, but when I try to access my Nextcloud content via Nautilus ("Files")(using the newly-created source/location icon on the side), I am told:

```
Unable to access "my.username@my.domain.com.au/nextcloud"
HTTP Error: Unauthorized
```

My current setup is configured to use two-factor authentication and as anyone who has used two-factor authentication will know, I need to configure an application-specific password from *within* Nextcloud, instead of using my "real" password... I have done this, and it has made no difference.

I also tried disabling two-factor authentication, just in case this was interferring with the login, and tested with both my "real" password and the application-specific password whilst two-factor authentication was off... No luck.

I am able to login to my Nextcloud server using a web browser, and also via the (official) Android application... I only have issues when I try to use Nautilus' ("Files'")/Ubuntu 18.04 LTS' built-in functionality.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any ideas, people?